# Android Studio: How to access the device is rooted to implement auto install the local APK file?

Tags: android

I have written code to download and open the installation screen where if user can allow to install it will get installed, but I required auto installation of app. So if someone have any trick to implement auto installation of local APK file using Android Studio. Please share.

Comment: Probably, Operating System will not allow to do so!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a security risk and wont be allowed by the operating system. 
I'm sure there's malware out there that can do it, but those often use exploits that are 'quickly'/eventually patched.